# Syntax for Kusto Query With Count

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

If I have 3 columns that one student studies multiple subjects:

StudentID | Subject | SubjectScore

And I want to find the total number of subjects for each `StudentID`, what should be the syntax for Kusto query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like this one

```
TableName
| summarize TotalSubjects = count() by StudentID
```

don't forget to change `TableName` with your actual table name